# How to setup IntelliJ IDEA to automatically add "final" where is possible

Tags: intellij-idea

I have one method like this.

```
public void test(String name) {

}
```

So when I click ctrl+alt+l I expect it add final format like below.

```
public void test(final String name) {

}
```

How to set coding style like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the checkbox `Preferences/Settings | Editor | Inspections | Java | Code Style issues | Local variable or parameter can be final` and perform the reformat code action.

If the [Code cleanup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/reformat-file-dialog.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2020.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product) checkbox is enabled then IDEA will automatically add final where possible.